# Проверка того, что хотя бы один 'checkbox' выбран

Tags: jquery

Есть тест, где вопросы открываются один за другим и мне нужно, что если пользователь не выбрал ни одного варианта ответа, то вывести ему предупреждение. 
У меня работает только для первого вопроса, а дальше нет.
помогите, пожалуйста

[Демо](https://jsfiddle.net/alcheez/jh5e3otx/8/)

```js
var answercount;

$("#flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").show("slow");
});
$(".send").click(function() {
 if($('input:radio:checked').prop("checked")){
  answercount = $(this).closest(".question").attr("id").split('-')[1];
  console.log(answercount);

  $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('hidden');
  answercount = answercount * 1 + 1;
  console.log(answercount);
  $('#question-' + answercount).toggleClass('hidden');
}
    else{
    alert('mistake');
 }
});
```

```css
#panel {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="flip" href="#here">Начать тестирование</a>
<div id="panel">
  <div class="question show" id="question-1">
    <h3>Выберите цитату, которая бы лучшим образом описывала ваше отношение к работе…</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">1. Все, что делаешь, надо делать хорошо, даже если совершаешь безумство. Оноре де Бальзак</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">2. Работай с умом, а не до ночи. Луций Анней Сенека</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">3. Работа отгоняет от нас три великих зла: скуку, порок и нужду. Вольтер</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Мне всегда лучше работается после того, как я послушаю музыку. Иоганн Вольфганг фон Гёте</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Ничего особенно не трудно, если разделить работу на небольшие части. Генри Форд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Нет никчемной работы, а есть никчемные люди, которых не устроит никакая работа. Айн Рэнд. Атлант расправил плечи</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Самая сильная мотивация - это работать, чтоб потом не работать. Соцсети</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="question hidden" id="question-2">
    <h3>Вам принесли газету. Какие новости вы пропустите и не станете читать?</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1. Новости эстрады и звезд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2. Финансовые и валютные котировки, бензин, погода</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3. Новости в политике и обществе</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Новости спорта</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Новости культуры</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Происшествия</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Новости айти и технологий</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вместо `$(".send").click(function() {` попробуйте написать `$("input .send").click(function() {`.

Comment: @DmitriyKondratiuk а почему submit? Не слышал, чтобы такие элементы UI назывались "submit".

Comment: Кнопка разве не часть пользовательського интерфейса `<input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">` просветите пожалуйста. Да и вопрос изначально другой был

Answer (score 7):

**Во-первых**, почему вы вообще в коде ищите инпуты radio, если у вас все вопросы checkbox? Т. е. нужно так:

```
$('input:checkbox:checked')
```

**Во-вторых**, только для первого вопроса у вас срабатывает условие потому, что после него чекнутые инпуты УЖЕ ЕСТЬ (вы же в первом вопросе выбрали что-то), соответсвенно, условие идёт по положительному варианту. Следовательно, нужно дополнительно фильтровать чекбоксы.

Накидал самый банальный вариант - [Демо на jsfiddle на всякий случай](https://jsfiddle.net/dlcwalkoff/jh5e3otx/9/)

```js
var answercount = 1;

function getCurrentQuestionElement(answercount) {
  return $('#question-' + answercount);
}

$("#flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").show("slow");
});

$(".send").click(function() {
  var currentQuestionElement = getCurrentQuestionElement(answercount);
  var inputRadioCheckedInCurrentQuestion = currentQuestionElement.find('input:checkbox:checked');
  var inputRadioCheckedInCurrentQuestionFirstProp = inputRadioCheckedInCurrentQuestion.prop("checked");

  if (!!inputRadioCheckedInCurrentQuestionFirstProp) {
    answercount = $(this).closest(".question").attr("id").split('-')[1];
    console.log(answercount);

    $('#question-' + answercount).addClass('hidden');
    answercount = answercount * 1 + 1;
    console.log(answercount);
    $('#question-' + answercount).toggleClass('hidden');
  } else {
    alert('mistake');
  }
});
```

```css
#panel {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="flip" href="#here">Начать тестирование</a>
<div id="panel">
  <div class="question show" id="question-1">
    <h3>Выберите цитату, которая бы лучшим образом описывала ваше отношение к работе…</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">1. Все, что делаешь, надо делать хорошо, даже если совершаешь безумство. Оноре де Бальзак</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">2. Работай с умом, а не до ночи. Луций Анней Сенека</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="sport">3. Работа отгоняет от нас три великих зла: скуку, порок и нужду. Вольтер</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Мне всегда лучше работается после того, как я послушаю музыку. Иоганн Вольфганг фон Гёте</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Ничего особенно не трудно, если разделить работу на небольшие части. Генри Форд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Нет никчемной работы, а есть никчемные люди, которых не устроит никакая работа. Айн Рэнд. Атлант расправил плечи</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Самая сильная мотивация - это работать, чтоб потом не работать. Соцсети</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="question hidden" id="question-2">
    <h3>Вам принесли газету. Какие новости вы пропустите и не станете читать?</h3>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">1. Новости эстрады и звезд</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">2. Финансовые и валютные котировки, бензин, погода</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">3. Новости в политике и обществе</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">4. Новости спорта</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">5. Новости культуры</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">6. Происшествия</label>
    <br>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox">7. Новости айти и технологий</label>
    <br>

    <p>
      <input class="send" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Присвойте галочкам из одного вопроса одинаковый класс или другое одинаковое свойство. И для проверки используйте foreach по этому классу.
Например:

```
mistake=1;
$( ".class1" ).each(function( index ) {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')==checked){
        mistake=0;
    }
}
if (mistake==1){
    alert('mistake');
}
```